# How to restore redmine on an ubuntu server after a dist-upgrade?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redmine, upgrade

I just became a new admin on a server (ubuntu-server virtual machine) that host redmine on apache2 and subversion in my company.

- I discovered that the OS is Ubuntu Raring 13.04 that is out of date from January 2014!
- I updated the `source.list` to replace xx.ubuntu.com by `old-releases.ubuntu.com`, then I made update && upgrade.
- So I made `do-release-upgrade`.

The script force remove the Redmine package.

I cloned the machine and ran two dist-upgrade successively on the cloned machine so I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 and then from 13.10 to 14.04 Trusty LTS and I choose to stay on the LTS.

The problem now is to restore redmine on the upgraded system. How to do that ? 
Two difficulties are added to this work because:

- ubuntu raring run postgresql-9.1, but trusty run 9.3. So the redmine db is on a 9.1 pg cluster.
- redmine itself was an old version and trusty repos host redmine-2.4.2-1

What is the key points to perform the restoration of the complete application configuration and datas ?

Comment: If you were lucky enough, you could have had `/root/redmine/redmine_bak` running as cronjob on every midnight. It will dump the database to redmine.sql and copy files to /root/redmine/. Otherwise you need to get postgresql-9.1 running somewhere in order to make the dump. Dumping databases before dist-upgrade is always a good idea.

Comment: Postgres clusters usually get automatically upgraded, can you access it?

Answer (score 3):

Your old data should be in /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/. Backup this folder first. Maybe, you even have an old Postgres server, that you could run, on /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/

Then you could try to move the data to the new postgres.

Useful links:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/upgrading.html

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60465/upgrading-from-postgres-9-1-to-9-3-on-ubuntu-server

As far as I understand, you need a Postgres 9.1 running to make pg_dump. See http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/install-postgresql-ubuntu-14-04/. If you cannot install it on 14.04, then you could run pg_dump on the original machine (which you cloned and which was not upgraded).

Another option would be pg_upgrade. Then you do not need to have running postgres 9.1 on your system. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgupgrade.html

When your DB is migrated to newer version of Postgres, you can start to upgrade Redmine.

As I understood, the Ubuntu 13.04 has Redmine version 1.4.4. It's quite old, so, probably, on your server it was installed from http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Download, rather than using apt-get. Then you could already have a newer version of Redmine.

Otherwise, you need to upgrade from 1.4.4 to 2.4.2. Follow this guide: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade. It would be also good if you could backup your Redmine directory or at least files (/var/lib/redmine/default/files) before upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I gave you the bounty because merited. Although I'll try it Monday or Thursday when I'll be able to the, I'll come back to accept the solution or comment again to more help. Thank you again.